# Unable to use gettext to retrieve the translated string in .mo files

Tags: php, locale, gettext, setlocale

I'm trying to setup a clean environment to test php's gettext with. I forked from one of the example and started there, but failed to get it work:
https://github.com/yookoala/gettext-example

(If needed, please clone the source code and test yourself)

The main portion of the PHP script:

```php
<?php
// set locale to either first argument or the $_GET['locale']
$localeToSet = $argv[1] ?? $_GET['locale'] ?? 'zh_HK.utf8';
if (($locale = setlocale(LC_ALL, [
    $localeToSet,
    "$localeToSet.utf8",
    "$localeToSet.utf-8",
    "$localeToSet.UTF8",
    "$localeToSet.UTF-8",
])) === false) {
    throw new Exception($localeToSet . ' is not supported in this system');
}

bindtextdomain('messages', 'locale');

textdomain('messages');

printf("locale: %s - \n", $locale);
printf(_("Hello, %s, it is nice to see you today.\n"), "Vic");
```

The `locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po` file:

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR Codegroove.net
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid   ""
msgstr  "Project-Id-Version: Codegroove.net Example Translations 0.0.1\n"
        "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: vmc@codegroove.net\n"
        "POT-Creation-Date: 2010-05-28 06:18-0500\n"
        "PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
        "Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
        "Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#, php-format
msgid   "Hello, %s, it is nice to see you today.\n"
msgstr "你好，%s，很高興今日與你會面。\n"
```

Both the CLI and PHP test server failed to show the translated text (as it is supposed to be). It's just showing the raw message.

Does anybody here have idea what is wrong with my setup? Or how I might trace the problem?

Comment: Maybe we could help if you told us something we could work with. What failed, how does it fail, did it give you error mesages, if so **what were they**

Comment: I'd expect to see the translated message. Instead, it only shows the untranslated string.

Comment: And there is no error message at all.

Comment: When you ask a question, read it back to yourself, _but pretent you are one of us_ If you read this information would you be able to help you?

Comment: I literally don't know what more I could do to help myself. I've provided all the information I could think of (include the full source code). Please advice if you think there's more I can give. Thanks.

Comment: Does php-gettext provide any debug message that I could enable?

Answer (score 1):

There is also a command-line version of gettext. Try this:

```
TEXTDOMAIN=messages TEXTDOMAINDIR=locale LC_ALL=zh_HK.UTF-8 gettext 'Hello, %s, it is nice to see you today.
>'
```

Instead of the newline, you have to hit ENTER and then add the closing quote. The `>` comes from your shell.

Does that work? Then you know that the problem lies in your code. And if it doesn't work, the problem is in your setup, your local environment. Try to see which directories and files are considered by `gettext`, for example with `strace` or so.

Other possible errors:

1. The translation is retrieved from an `mo` file, not a `po` file. Does it exist? Try `msgunfmt locale/zh_HK/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo`.
2. Try to specify an absolute path for the locale directory with `bindtextdomain('messages', '/path/to/locale');`
3. Are you using Windows?

What locale is actually used? You didn't post the output of your script.